# GitLab CI Pipeline Variable based on Changes Path

Tags: gitlab

I have a monorepo with a bunch of services defined in it. I'd like to have each service has their own pipeline, so teams can work independently.

Here is a sample of my pipeline code:

```
.backend:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      changes:
        - "backend/**/*"
      when: always

backend-build:
  stage: build
  extends: .backend
  needs: []
  script:
    - echo "Compiling the backend code..."

backend-test:
  stage: test
  extends: .backend
  needs: ["backend-build"]
  script:
    - echo "Testing the backend code..."
```

I've tried adding rules with changes to set a variable at the root of .gitlab-ci.yml like so:

```
rules:
  - changes:
      - "backend/**/*"
    variables:
      TEST_VAR: backend
  - changes:
      - "frontend/**/*"
    variables:
      TEST_VAR: frontend

include: '/templates/.example.yml'
```

But I get the following error: `jobs rules config should implement a script: or a trigger: keyword`.

How can I accomplish keeping my code dry but referring to the same block of code for multiple `rules:changes:paths`?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up generating pipeline YAML using Python, creating an artifact and then triggering a child pipeline using the YAML. Here's my .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
stages:
  - triggers
  - triggered
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

generate-config-mr:
  stage: triggers
  image: python:3.11.5-alpine3.18
  script:
    - pip install -q requests Jinja2
    - python gitlab/build-pipeline.py $GENERATED_CONFIG_FILE # Tell the script where the write the config
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - $GENERATED_CONFIG_FILE

generate-config-default:
  stage: triggers
  # Using this image to get the git executable
  image: cicirello/pyaction:4.29.0
  script:
    - pip install -q requests Jinja2 GitPython
    - python gitlab/build-pipeline.py $GENERATED_CONFIG_FILE # Tell the script where the write the config
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - $GENERATED_CONFIG_FILE
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH

mr-child-pipeline:
  stage: triggered
  trigger:
    include:
      - artifact: child-pipeline.yml
        job: generate-config-mr
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'

default-child-pipeline:
  stage: triggered
  trigger:
    include:
      - artifact: child-pipeline.yml
        job: generate-config-default
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
```

I used Jinja2 to generate the YAML:

```
{% for cell in variables %}
{{ cell }}-build:
  stage: build
  image: mycustomimage
  script:
    - echo "Compiling the {{ cell }} code..."
  rules:
    - when: on_success

{{ cell }}-test:
  stage: test
  image: mycustomimage
  script:
    - echo "Testing the {{ cell }} code..."
  rules:
    - when: on_success
{% endfor %}
```